# Symfony2: How to persist a new User in an admin-interface with FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm creating the admin view where i can list the users and create the users.
I have created the `User` class but i am not sure how can i persist it.

Do I need to manually create the form and then persist it?

I have saved using normal save but then there is validation performed.

I want to know wether I need to manually encode password etc. or `FOSUserBundle` will do that for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your aren't planning to use ...

- the default `/register` [route](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml) / [method](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L34) for new users
- the console [command](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md): `app/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssword`

... as you're talking about an **admin** (web)-interface.

---

**Answer:**

In a `ContainerAware` class (i.e. controllers) ...

... you can re-use the default registration-form and disable validation:

```
$user = new User();
$this->createForm(
    $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.type'),
    $user,
    array(
       'validation_groups' => false,
    )
);
```

Here's how to manually create a new `User` and persist it to the database:

```
$om      = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');     
$manager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

$user = $manager->createUser();

$user
    ->setUsername('nifr')
    ->setEmail('dont@spam.me')
    ->setPlainPassword('Insecure123')
    ->setEnabled(true)
;

$om->persist($user);
$om->flush();
```

Comment: But i have extended User class from Fosuser class and have extra fields , so i had to create new form myself. But i am not sure when i submit my new form then how to persist taht new form along with Fosuser data

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. That's a different thing. My answers your question in the current form. I couldn't see that your User entity includes custom fields. Please open a new question asking how to re-use/extend FOSUserBundle's registration form to include custom fields.